# Azure - Should I configure Retry Policy in Azure function or in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

How to apply retry policy if you have a logic app that contains an azure function. Where are you gonna put the retry policy, in the logic app or function?

I know for Azure you can have a retry policy for both logic app or functions.

Logic App Retry: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling

Function level Retry: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=csharp

Suppose I have a simple logic app that contains a HTTP trigger with a function(name it FuncA) connect to it:

(Logic App Designer:)

```
HttpTrigger
    |
  FuncA
```

Other things gonna call the logic app URL to invoke FuncA.

If I want some retry policy, should I configure it in Logic App Designer or change the setting in the function itself (function.json file etc.)?

If I have both configured, will the retry be triggered twice? What's the best practice?

Also, let's assume I have another logic app:

```
HttpTrigger
    |
  FuncA
    |
 send Email
```

Will the retry of FuncA also trigger the following send Email? or it only retry it self?

Thanks,

Henry

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to say anything without knowing more context, especially what the nature of the thing being done.

Comment: @NoahStahl Hi Noah, the question is just about how to apply retry policy if you have a logic app that contains an azure function. Where you gonna put the retry policy, in logic app or function.

Comment: I was suggesting you describe or show what exactly is the function doing. And why the logic app is involved at all.